# String literal and object relation in Java

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, string-constant

Suppose I have a string literal like,

```
String s1 = "ABC";
```

And another String object like,

```
String s2 = new String("ABC");
```

So is there any connection or relation between String `s1` and `s2` from java's memory point of view, as `s1` is in the string constant pool and `s2` is in the heap memory.

Comment: Please note that you are expected to do some research prior asking questions.